# Values for a and b Diagonalizable Over C

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

For which values of $a$ and $b$ is the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
b & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$?

I know that if $a = -1$ and $b = 1$, then the matrix is diagonalizable. However, I am not sure if that is the only solution or how to go about finding solutions in general. Please help.

Comment: Do you know how to find the eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, I do--vaguely. What I tried doing was looking at the characteristic polynomial to help, and I came up with a difference of two squares. I don't really think that is correct though since it seems to easy.

Answer (score 3):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\b&0\end{pmatrix}\implies p_A(x):=\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}\;x&\!\!-a\\\!\!-b&\;x\end{vmatrix}=x^2-ab$$

so

$$p_A(x)=0\iff x=\pm\sqrt{ab}\implies$$

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;ab\neq0\implies\;\text{there are two different eigenvalues and the matrix is diagonalizable}$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;ab=0\;,\;a\neq 0\,\,\vee\,\,b\neq0\implies\text{ this is a non-zero nilpotent matrix and thus non-diagonalizable}$$

$$(3)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;a=b=0\implies\text{ the matrix's already diagonal...}$$

Comment: That, again, was an act of god, @Amzoti...:P) Thanks for catching that and corrected.

Comment: you are very welcome! Nice solution! +1

Comment: That @julien , what to do!, was again the hand of god. It should have been non-diagonalizable. Thanks.